# Differentiate between 2 correlations - correlation vs causation

Tags: statistics, correlation, cross-correlation

I am comparing two types of crops, let's call them crop A and B.
I have data from ~1000 farms on growth of the plants (average per farm) and want to correlate growth to crop type.

Unfortunately, the different farms also use different fertilizers (fertilizer 1...10), and some have changed the fertilizer used over time...

So, I want to show (with statistical significance) that the growth of crop type A exceeds the growth of crop type B, but make sure it is not coincidence because of the fertilizer used. Can you point me to a statistical test for this purpose? Or do I need to split the data into subgroups (that each contain only one fertilizer) and draw separate conclusions from each subgroup?

Thanks for any hints!
best wishes
Peter.

[image: Data overview]

Comment: This is an interesting question, but more suited for stats.stackexchange.com. My brief advice is that the big picture here is to quantify the effect of fertilizer type. The general concept is to look at effect size rather than looking at a zero/nonzero significance test. As you know, a significance test must lead you to reject the null hypothesis for large enough sample size, if the difference is actually nonzero, as it likely is in this case (as in many others). Therefore a significance test tells only "you have a big sample" / "you don't have a big sample" which isn't a useful conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The type of fertilizer is a confounding variable which you need to control, in order to reduce it's effect on your statistical test.

Assuming all crop types might use all fertilizer types, a good way to control that confounding variable is by [simple stratification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling)

The data sampled is divided into two group (crop A, crop B) which are stratified by fertilizer type – to reduce its impact.